# Getting an OAuth access token (not language specific) - same issue for Flickr and Tumblr, but not Twitter

Tags: php, oauth, access-token, flickr, hmacsha1

I'm making the huge mistake of writing my own OAuth library and wrapper classes in PHP.  Everything works wonderfully for Twitter's OAuth implementation, but I fail on signing the access_token step for both Tumblr and Flickr.

The ONLY difference in that step, is now I have oauth_token and oauth_verifier parameters.  I'm using the Authorization header, and the only problem I can think of is that there are some character encoding issues, but I'm not sure.

**Base string** (broken for clarity):

```
POST&
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.flickr.com%2Fservices%2Foauth%2Faccess_token&
oauth_consumer_key%3Deeedfcd4c46a2c12080f58eb90a974d8
%26oauth_nonce%3D322190b47ca680d053338724ad1cc56d35d3e7b5
%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1
%26oauth_timestamp%3D1322981994
%26oauth_token%3D72157628270097303-18aa378b4ab02af3
%26oauth_verifier%3Dec7811503fdd4380
%26oauth_version%3D1.0
```

This is exactly what Flickr expects (they tell me so in the error response), which leads me to believe the signature is the problem.

**Authorization header** (also broken for clarity):

```
Authorization: OAuth
oauth_consumer_key="eeedfcd4c46a2c12080f58eb90a974d8", 
oauth_nonce="322190b47ca680d053338724ad1cc56d35d3e7b5",
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
oauth_timestamp="1322981994",
oauth_token="72157628270097303-18aa378b4ab02af3",
oauth_verifier="ec7811503fdd4380",
oauth_version="1.0",
oauth_signature="LYJtgHetQWNKX3rtQlSs643FdWY%3D"
```

**And Flickr's response**:

```
oauth_problem=signature_invalid&
debug_sbs=POST&
    http%3A%2F%2Fwww.flickr.com%2Fservices%2Foauth%2Faccess_token&
    oauth_consumer_key%3Deeedfcd4c46a2c12080f58eb90a974d8
    %26oauth_nonce%3D322190b47ca680d053338724ad1cc56d35d3e7b5
    %26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1
    %26oauth_timestamp%3D1322981994
    %26oauth_token%3D72157628270097303-18aa378b4ab02af3
    %26oauth_verifier%3Dec7811503fdd4380
    %26oauth_version%3D1.0
```

There are no GET or POST parameters.  Everything seems to be escaped correctly from what I see here.  The signing works for the request_token step (and for Twitter, for ANY request).  I've verified that my server clock is within a second of theirs.  Am I missing something obvious?  How would you go about diagnosing this?

Comment: what exactlty is the problem you are getting,i mean the error?

Comment: Haha.  Got so focused on giving all my info that I forgot the error.  Sorry, one sec!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer my own question.

There were a few discrepancies between the different oauth service provider implementations:

**Twitter**

- Expects oauth_callback on request_token step
- Doesn't return oauth_token_secret until access_token response
- Therefore, there's an empty oauth_token_secret in signing the access_token request

**Flickr & Tumblr**

- Expect oauth_callback on authenticate (i.e. authorize) step
- Return oauth_token_secret on request_token step (and expect you to remember it and use it to sign access_token request)

**Youtube (and other Google OAuth service providers):**

- Expects Google-proprietary "scope" on request_token step
- Expects oauth_callback on authenticate (i.e. OAuthAuthorizeToken) step
- Doesn't seem to like oauth_token passed in Authorization header in the access_token step (responds with "token invalid" due to required double-encoding in base string).  Pass it in the post body or query string instead.

Comment: I am stuck in how to get the access_token from tumblr. I got oauth_token_secret & oauth_token from tumblr but don't know how to get access_token now. If I use oauth_token as access_token here then tumblr gives an Authentication warning. Also please let me know if there is any use of oauth_verifier in this process? Please help me. I have already wasted 2 days on the same.